# How to disable ThrottlingConfigurations from deployment.toml in WSO2 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apacheds

I am configuring Apache DS user store in WSO2 3.0.0. All the user store configuration I have given in deployment.toml file. But while starting the server it is giving the below error. After searching that looks like this error is coming as  is enable in api-manager.xml, but I am not able to disable it from deployment.toml. Can anyone help me with the configuration I should provide in deployment.toml to make it disabled. Also from the error log it seems like server is also searching for JMS but not enable. Please help me with this also. Error given below:

```
[2020-01-28 18:39:57,261]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2020-01-28 18:39:57,263]  INFO - DataBridge user admin connected
[2020-01-28 18:39:57,269] ERROR - AuthenticationServiceImpl Invalid User : admin
[2020-01-28 18:39:57,270] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://<local_machine_ip>:9711.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://<local_machine_ip>:9711.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:145) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/<local_machine_ip>:9711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.authentication.AuthenticationException: Invalid User : admin
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor269.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:163) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
        ... 6 more
```

Please Note: I am running WSO2 3.0.0 in local windows machine for POC.

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the configuration to disable data publishing to the traffic manager, and the JMS listener.

```
[apim.throttling]
enable_data_publishing = false
enable_decision_connection = false
```

Comment: Thanks Bee , this configuration worked. After this the above error gone, but getting some other error for JMS Listener and AMQ. So is there any WSO2 official documentation for deployment.toml setup. Need to know how can I override the default setup of JMS, ActiveMQ for WSO2 3.0.0

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener} - Connection attempt : 11 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 7200 seconds                                   {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} - Throwable Received but no listener set. org.wso2.andes.AMQException: AMQP timed out when attempting to close the connection

Comment: try with `enable_decision_connection = false`. updated the answer.